# How to fill a DataFrame till specific row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like the one below and I want to add a new column to it. So that this column has a value up to a certain row and another value for the rest. How can I do this?

```
    f1       f2       f3  ...     f10000
0  0.037026  0.037026  0.037026  ...  0.000000
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.004047
...
```

I know I can add columns using the following command, but I do not know how to specify that  the value change after a specific row (for example row 1).

```
df['new_col'] = '1'
```

What I get:

```
    f1       f2       f3  ...     f10000       new_col
0  0.037026  0.037026  0.037026  ...  0.000000  1
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  1
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.004047  1
...
```

What I want:

```
    f1       f2       f3  ...     f10000       new_col
0  0.037026  0.037026  0.037026  ...  0.000000  1
1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.004047  0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index for compare values, here is set `1` if index is less like `1` else `0` in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
N = 0
df['new_col'] = np.where(df.index <= N, 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['new_col'] = (df.index <= N).astype(int)
```

Another idea is compare array created by length of DataFrame:

```
arr = np.arange(len(df))
df['new_col'] = np.where(arr <= 0, 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['new_col'] = (arr <= N).astype(int)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `1, 1, 0 `?

Comment: the first `1` is part of the condition `arr < 1` or `df.index < 1`, the next `1` is the `if true` part of the statement then `0` is the `else` part

Comment: @Flodude - Then it create `1,1,0`, you think `df['new_col'] = np.where(df.index <= 0, 1, 0)` for `1,0,0` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might assign `list` rather than single value which is then broadcast. Length of said list must be equal to number of records in your DataFrame, consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
df['new_col'] = [1]+[0]*2
print(df)
```

Output

```
   A  B  new_col
0  1  4        1
1  2  5        0
2  3  6        0
```

Explanation: I harnessed python's ability to multiply list by positive integer to get desired number of repetition of list then contatenated `[1]` with such created list (this give same effect as doing `df['new_col'] = [1,0,0]`)